# Why do we need nested Select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT  A.country 
       ,A.market 
       ,SUM(COALESCE(A.sales_value,0)) AS local_currency_sales
FROM 
(
    SELECT  country 
           ,market 
           ,local_currency_sales
    FROM TABLE 
) A
GROUP BY  A.country
         ,A.market
```

The above is the pseudo code I am referring to. I am new to SQL and would like to ask the reason that if there is a need to have a nested Select like this above? I tried to remove the nested `Selected` and it throws an error: `country` must appear in the Group By Clause. What I would like to know is that intuitively, the below should work even with Group by

```
SELECT  A.country 
       ,A.market 
       ,SUM(COALESCE(A.sales_value,0)) AS local_currency_sales

    FROM TABLE A
GROUP BY  A.country
         ,A.market
```

Comment: The outer query makes no sense because it is using `SUM()` without `GROUP BY`.  At this point, you should add sample data which explains why your query is supposed to be doing.  Note: Your query basically would only ever run on MySQL, but not other databases.

Comment: You need to include the joining and groupby clauses, you can't post _half_ of a query and expect us to explain what is going on. The omitted clauses probably explain the requirement. It does however seem like a redundant nested select in this current form, usually a query like this may have started out with a genuine need to be nested but the nested window function may have been refactored out of it.

Comment: Your second query is correct, have you tried to run it? what is your question here? where did you get the guidance to nest the select in the first query? So many questions...

Comment: Your _pseudo code_ is not _pseudo_ at all, it really doesn't make sense, its just really bad SQL. So I don't think it is a good idea for you to use it as a reference, or for us to even contemplate explaining it. There are definite times to use nested and correlated queries but this is not one of them.

Comment: Your *pseudo code* is synthactically wrong, it will cause "unknown column" eror.

Comment: Show us the query without the subquery and show us what fails about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original post does not need a sub query at all, in fact the first query will not execute because it is trying to perform a `SUM` over a column that is not defined. The following adaptation might help explain how this works:

```
SELECT  A.CName
       ,A.M
       ,SUM(A.Sales) AS local_currency_sales
FROM 
(
    SELECT  country as CName
           ,market as M
           ,COALESCE(A.sales_value,0) as Sales
    FROM TABLE 
) A
GROUP BY  A.CName
         ,A.M
```

The use of Sub-Queries is usually to make the query easier to read or maintain. In this example you can see that the nested query evaluates the `COALESCE` function and has aliased the column names.

> It is important to note that the outer query can only access the columns that are returned from the inner query *AND* that they can only be accessed by aliases that have been assigned.

In advanced scenarios you might use nested queries to manually force query optimisations, however most database engines will have very good query optimisations by default, so it is important to recognise that nested queries can easily get in the way of standard optimisations and if done poorly may negatively affect performance.

There are of course some types of expressions that cannot be used in `Order By`, and `Group By` clauses. When you come across these conditions it might be neccessary to nest the query so that  you can group or sort by the results of those evaluations.

- Window functions is a prime example of this requirement.

> The specific queries where this becomes important are different for each RDBMS, and they each have their own workarounds or alternate implementations that may be more efficient than using a sub-query at all. The specifics are outside the scope of this post.

The simple form of your query that you have posted is all you need in this case:

```
SELECT  A.country 
       ,A.market 
       ,SUM(COALESCE(A.sales_value,0)) AS local_currency_sales
FROM TABLE A
GROUP BY  A.country
         ,A.market
```